# invariant of binary search for finding first occurrence of an element

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search, invariants

I have a problem with defining the invariant of finding the first element of a binary search. (I have a sorted array a and I want to find the first element that is equal to some number q and if it does not exist return -1)

First, I set this invariant for my while.

My invariant

> "Always a[l]<= q and also a[r] > q" ==> "Always l <= ind and also > ind".

Up to my invariant, I wrote this code:

```
int l=0,r=n;
while(l<r){
    int mid=(r+l)/2;
    if(a[mid]==q){
        r=mid+1;
    }
    else{
        if(a[mid]>q){
            r=mid;
        }else if(a[mid]<q) l=mid+1;
    }
}
return l;
```

But there is a problem that `if(a[mid]==q)` then I must pick an `r` that doesn't violate my invariant.

If I choose `mid-1` I will violate it because `a[r]` will be <= `q`.

And I must iterate through my indices until I find an index I that `a[i]>q` and then set `r` to that index. (r=i)==>But If I do this it's not `O(log n)`

And I have seen some code implementing `lower_bound` that `if(a[mid]==q)` the set `r` to `mid` but I think they are violating they invariant but they code are correct and return the correct value.

Like this code:

```
1- int l = 0;
2- int r = n; // Not n - 1
3- while (l < r) {
4-     int mid = (l + r) / 2;
5-     if (q <= a[mid]) {
6-         r = mid;
7-     } else {
8-         l = mid + 1;
9-     }
10- }
11- return l;
```

At the first, The invariant is like my invariant(`i` is on the range of `[l,r)` )  but in line 5 consider `if(q==a[mid])` then obviously it's violating because its( `[l,r]` because `r` is equal and it can be the first occurrence).

Am I right or I don't have the correct understanding concept of invariant?

Comment: I think the invariant should be `l < x and r >= x` then finally return `r`

Comment: @AndrewScoot Why I cant use this invariant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have a sequence

```
..., <q, <q, <q, q, q, ..., q, q, >q, >q, >q, ...
                 ^ (*)
```

where `<q` (`>q`) stands for any element `< q` (`> q`). We want to find the point (*).

We have two pointers, `left < right`. How can we use them to distinguish that point? The answer is simple: `left` should point to the last `<q` element, `right` should point to the first `q` element:

```
..., <q, <q, <q, q, q, ..., q, q, >q, >q, >q, ...
                 ^ right
             ^ left
```

The invariant is: `*left < q` and `*right >= q`.

The invariant that you suggested, `*left <= q` and `*right > q` corresponds to the last element in that sequence:

```
..., <q, <q, <q, q, q, ..., q, q, >q, >q, >q, ...
                                  ^ right
                               ^ left
```

Some references that can be useful:

- Col.4: *Writing correct programs* – J.Bentley. *Programming pearls*. Addison-Wesley, 2<sup>nd</sup> ed., 1999.
  [Book website](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-pearls-second/9780134498058/)
- J.Bentley. *Programming pearls: Writing correct programs*. Communications of the ACM **26**, [1040](https://doi.org/10.1145/358476.358484) (1983).
  [Full text](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/jon-bentley/correct-programs.pdf)
- Invariants for binary search – Dr.Dobb's Journal
  [Part I](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/invariants-for-binary-search-part-1-a-si/240169169),
  [Part II](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/invariants-for-binary-search-part-2-refi/240169199),
  [Part III](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/invariants-for-binary-search-part-3-impr/240169239),
  [Part IV](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/invariants-for-binary-search-part-4-usin/240169267),
  [Part V](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/abstractions-for-binary-search-part-5-ge/240169289),
  [Part VI](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/abstractions-for-binary-search-part-6-ho/240169326),
  [Part VII](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/abstractions-for-binary-search-part-7-ch/240169367),
  [Part VIII](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/abstractions-for-binary-search-part-8-wh/240169392),
  [Part IX](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/abstractions-for-binary-search-part-9-wh/240169416),
  [Part X](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/abstractions-for-binary-search-part-10-p/240169437)

Comment: So in this problem, I can only use this invariant==>"left<q and right>=q" Am I right?

Comment: @AiraBanazadeh, if you want to find the *first* `q`, yes.

Comment: Thank you, How I can find invariant for questions like this? ( I mean can I solve and find invariants of all the binary search questions with your logic in your answer?)

Comment: @AiraBanazadeh, I can't say for *all* binary search questions, but the idea is always the same. If you want a more detailed explanation, take a look at some references I've added to the answer.

Comment: can you provide me the link of the pdf of Programming Pearls?